# RSpec gives 'undefined method' for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a `User` model. Code here:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :fistname, :lastname, presence: true
end
```

DB schema for Users looks like this:

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
  end
```

And I have some test suite. I uses Rspec and my `user_spec.rb` file looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  it { should validate_presence_of :firstname }
  it { should validate_presence_of :lastname }
end
```

But when I run test I gets from terminal this message:

> 3) User should require lastname to be set
>        Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of :lastname }
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `fistname' for #

So what is the problem?
Some problem with RSpec?
It looks like the test database isn't up to date (I've added this fields (firstname, lastname) later).

When I typed `bin/rake db:test:prepare` i get info that it is deprecated.

Comment: You have a typo mistake in `User` model: fi[no "r" here]stname.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! Two hours spends on research in Google about RSpec and test BD. But why the problem was also for the 'lastname'?

Comment: not sure when it was introduced but a quick google shows that rails 4.1 doesn't need `rake db:test:prepare`.  if you're running 4.0.x, you may need to run that first.

Comment: Because RSpec uses the whole your code to behave the model, but checks the presence of `:lastname` only in this particular test.

Comment: In fact it will be better to delete this question, because it's not about programming problem.

Comment: I agree but I can't delete because this question has the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a TYPO in user model
Validates "fistname" should be "firstname"
See the missing r